# Unknow tag .xhtml jsf <f: selectItems />

Tags: jsf-2, facelets

This is the Facelet:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


 <html xmlns ="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

 <h:head>
 <title>Title</title>
 </h:head>

 <h:body>
 <h:form>
 <h:commandButton value ="Converter" action ="#{conversorMonetarioBean.converte}"/>
 <h:inputText value ="#{conversorMonetarioBean.valor}"/>

 <h:outputLabel value ="de" for ="de"/>

 <h:selectOneMenu value ="#{conversorMonetarioBean.de}" id="de">
 <f:selectItems 
    value ="#{conversorMonetarioBean.taxas.keySet()}"
    var ="moeda"
    itemValue ="#{moeda}"
    itemLabel ="#{moeda}" />
 </h:selectOneMenu>

 <h:outputLabel value ="para" for ="para"/>

 <h:selectOneMenu value ="#{conversorMonetarioBean.para}" id="para">
 <f:selectItems
     value ="#{conversorMonetarioBean.taxas.keySet()}"
     var ="moeda"
     itemValue ="#{moeda}"
     itemLabel ="#{moeda}"  /> 
 </h:selectOneMenu>
 </h:form>



<h:outputFormat value ="{0} em {1} equivale a {2} em {3}" rendered ="#{conversorMonetarioBean.resultado != null}">
 <f:param value ="#{conversorMonetarioBean.valor}"/>
 <f:param value ="#{conversorMonetarioBean.de}"/>
 <f:param value ="#{conversorMonetarioBean.resultado}"/>
 <f:param value ="#{conversorMonetarioBean.para}"/>
 </h:outputFormat>
</h:body>
</html>
```

It's saying that f:selectItems is an unknown tag.

What could be wrong ? I'm using JSF2, GlassFish 3.1.2, Eclipse. I tried to ctrl+space and only have h:something tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot to import `f` namespace in your `html` declaration, `xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"`, so that the top section will be like:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
```

Also, your IDE is possibly showing you a hint that `f` namespace is missing, so following its instructions to do the import will solve your problem.